# Preferred style for writing to database MVVM c#

Tags: c#, sql, mvvm

Using WPF MVVM is there a preferred practice for organizing code when saving an object?

For example is it preferred to use option A

```
MyObject.Save()
```

Or option B

```
SqlHelper.Save(MyObject)
```

I like the idea of using the SqlHelper approach because it organizes all the code related to the SQL Server in one place. If I want to save the object to a file then I would also have a `FileHelper.Save()` class. Furthermore `MyObject.Save()` could call `SqlHelper.Save(this)`.

Is there a preferred style for c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if you follow good principles of software design (e.g. [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), etc.) you will find that your `MyObject` class should only have one responsibility because of [the "Single Responsibility Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Therefore, it should not know how to save itself because it already has another responsibility, which is containing information or data -- I'm making the assumption here that `MyObject` is a POCO.

So, the second approach is getting there, you don't want to have a SqlHelper that is in charge of performing the SQL operations for *all* objects/classes -- for the same reason above: it should only have *one* responsibility.  You should make a SQL data mapper class *specific* to `MyObject` with CRUD operations on it.  That way, if anything ever changes with how you persist `MyObject` data, it won't affect the way other classes persist their data.

> Is there a preferred style for c#?

There are good principles that apply to all software design in any language, not just C#.

Comment: I'm not using entity framework. But since this is a style question, can you elaborate on what you would call a SQL Data mapper class and where you would organize it?

Comment: First, I'm assuming this is SQL Server (you didn't tag your DBMS), but it doesn't really matter.  This is a little outside the scope of this particular question, but what you want to do is have a data layer that is separate from your business/logic/domain layer (where you put your POCOs and do all the business logic).

Comment: In the data layer, there would be an abstract data mapper class (or interface) that has CRUD methods for `MyObject`, but no technology-specific aspects (e.g. SQL Server) should be in that class.  You could extend that class (or implement the interface) with a concrete "SQL Server data mapper" that has the actual SQL Server code for persisting your `MyObject` data.

Comment: I would also recommend injecting your concrete SQL Server data mapper into your application from the root (the app.cs) because it's always better to inject your dependencies (see: DI and IoC containers).  DI is a big topic, so I invite you to read up about it.